# Windows 10 printer works only after suspend cycle

Tags: windows-10, printing

When printing documents to our office network printer (HP Officejet Pro 8500) under Windows 10 Enterprise, I get printer errors (offline, unavailable, unknown, ...), despite the fact that the printer works perfectly for everyone else.

There is no additional info in the event logs, and no troubleshooting wizard can find anything wrong.

When I suspend and wake up my computer, the printer spews out all my queued documents!

If I then try to print new documents, the printer is not working anymore. That is, until the next suspend cycle.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Thank you @networkkingpin! Step 1 solved the problem perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these steps.

**Step 1**: Clear all jobs from a print queue.

1. Click on start button, type services and press enter.
2. Right-click Print Spooler and select Stop.
3. Now again click on start button, type C:\WINDOWS\System32\spool\PRINTERS and press enter.
4. Delete all the files in PRINTERS folder.
5. Go Services window Right-click Print Spooler and select Start.
6. Now check if you can print.

**Step 2**: Check the Spooler service on the desktop:

It appears to me that the Printer Spooler service is not starting on the desktop when you send a print job to the desktop. When you print from your Computer, check the status print spooler service, before restarting the desktop. If it’s started, stop and restart the same follow the steps:

1. Click Start, type services.msc and hit Enter.
2. Look for the Print spooler.
3. Restart the print spooler service.

Also make sure that the service is set to Automatic:
a.     Right click on service and click on Printer spooler service and click on Properties.
b.     Under the startup type, set it to ‘Automatic’.
c. click recovery options and make sure its set to always restart on errors

**Step 3**: Disable Bidirectional printing:

It could also be possible that you are having issues with bidirectional printing. Disable bidirectional printing and check if you have the same issue:
If you encounter a problem with bidirectional printing, disable bidirectional printing and resend your print job.

To disable bidirectional printing, do the following:

1. Click Start, and search for Devices click Printers.
2. Right-click the printer, and then click Properties.
3. Click the Ports tab, clear enable bidirectional support checkbox, and then click OK.

Comment: Would like to add to step 2 to make sure the printer spooler service is set to start automatically and has the recovery options to always restart on errors set. In my humble opinion W10 is still some steps away from being enterprise ready. As on many of our (about 2-3 years old) systems diverse services are crashing randomly and have to have the above settings set.

Comment: I will add that in. And I agree with you on that. We are still using windows 7 enterprise at my workplace.